# Easy selection of APKs in appium when testing same application but different APK files for different environments

Tags: ruby, appium

First an introduction to the problem.

We have been testing 5 websites that has 3 instances of testing environments (testing environment, pre-production environment and production environment), so, 3 different URLs, but exact same website.

The workaround with selenium-webdriver and ruby that we use is to set an environment variable, and in the webdriver test cases, we add a "case" in the "before" section of the tests, so is easier to set which instance we need to run our tests.

Now, problem is, that we are starting to use appium to test our APKs, and we are facing the same situation, we have some APKs, that also has 3 instances of testing environments.

Now the question is, if it's possible to implement this with appium, we have the appium.txt but maybe there's another method in which we can have the capabilities and apk in the same ruby file, so we can use a "case" as we do with the websites, because we can't use a case in the appium.txt file.

Here's the appium.txt file:

```
[caps]
platformName = "Android"
deviceName = "Android"
app = "./application.apk"
appPackage = "com.application.android.player"
appActivity = ".Main"
```

And here's my spec_helper.rb file:

```
# encoding: UTF-8
require 'rubygems'
require 'appium_lib'

def setup_driver
  return if $driver
  @caps = Appium.load_appium_txt file: File.join(Dir.pwd, 'appium.txt')
  if using_sauce
    upload_app
  end
  $driver=Appium::Driver.new(@caps)
end

RSpec.configure do |config|

  config.before(:each) do
    $driver.start_driver
    set_wait(10) #Implicit Wait
    wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 30)
    wait.until { find_element(:name,'TÉRMINOS Y CONDICIONES') }
    find_element(:id, 'com.application.android.player:id/acceptButton').click
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    $driver.driver_quit
  end

end
```

Comment: 3 QUESTIONS:            1) 3 test env means 3 APKs ???? 
2) Which means 3 appPackage? 3) You what to test all on same devices and in parallel or on 3 different devices or on same device, one APK at a time????????

Comment: yes, we have 3 different apks files, one per each environment, mean, 1 apk to test the "testing" environment, other to test pre-production environment, and the final production environment APK... so each week, we test a different environment, so no, not to run in parallel, only one at a time, on one device

Comment: you will have to keep a `var` in a some `read_config.rb` this file will read a appium.cfg file which will contain package other properties for your apks and that var it can be 1, 2 and 3. Details I shall be able to mail you. connect with me if required I have implemented similar scenario.